# Configuring multiple Certificate Distribution Points on a Cisco VPN Gateway which are ALL checked

Tags: certificate, vpn, cisco, pki, ca

I have an architecture where there is a single root CA and multiple sub-CA's.  Each sub-CA publishes certificates for devices in it's "domain".  Within each domain is a VPN gateway (Cisco router).  I would like to determine if it is possible to devise a configuration where each domain's VPN gateway would be able to check to see if the connecting device's certificate has been revoked at it's domain's sub-CA or another of the other domain's sub-CAs.  I'm also looking for the most efficient solution which would require as little configuration as possible when adding new domains.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A CRL or OCSP response has the serial number of the revoked certificate in a list, which is signed by the issuing CA or OCSP responder.  This ensures that when I revoke certificate serial no `123456789` on my CA that the certificate with the same serial number but issued by your CA isn't revoked instead.  Certificate serial numbers, although long, aren't globally unique.

From a security perspective, the ability to revoke another CA's certificates would just cause mayhem and the consequences would be dire.

The only CA that can revoke a certificate is the one that issued it.

Comment: Understood, but could a Cisco router be configured to check multiple CRLs or OCSP responders to see if the certificate it'd just been presented has been revoked by any of the sub-CA's?  Global serial number uniqueness shouldn't be an issue here as we're only talking about dozens of certificates issued.

Comment: Global serial numbers might not be an issue for you, but the protocol is fixed (RFC 5280 - a great bedtime read) and unless you start rewriting a ton of code, you're stuck with it ;-).  One thought that crossed my mind was indirect CRLs, but they're not well supported; and I'm not certain they'd help you anyway (more homework would be needed).

Comment: Your certificates are on network devices, which should be secured - how often do you envisage revoking certs?  Chances are, if you look after your network devices, that you'll never need to revoke anyway.  It would be a different story if you were looking at smartphone or user certs, which can easily be compromised. Are you looking for a solution to a problem that doesn't exist? Or is there a specific reason you're investigating this.